# OAuth C# server

Tags: c#, oauth

I want to create portal that would allow for user to use users data for logging to another sites (like FB). Is there any .NET OAuth server implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to use [this library](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth) (the one stated above) in my project to implement a provider on a server hosting a RESTful webservice. Follow [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777665/c-sharp-oauth-provider) to see how I'm doing ! I hope this will work so it helps you and others.

Comment: @rene : I think it uses oauth 1.0a. Anyway, OAuth 2.0 is a bad protocol (so says one of it's makers here : http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) and is still in draft state. OAuth 1.0a is stable and more secure, closer to what was intended in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

At least [one implementation](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth) showed up in Google. Not used it and I wonder if the code base is up to the latest standard: