# C# OAuth provider

Tags: c#, oauth, provider

I am struggling with the understanding of the [OAuthProvider Library](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuthProvider).  I am also struggling to understand the following [oauth-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/)

I am trying to implement am OAuth provider in my custom RESTful webservice. I am familiar with OAuth already as I implemented an OAuth 1.0a client already (using the amazing RESTsharp library). I just don't get how to use this library which to be honest seems to be the simplest one I could find (dotnetopenoauth is a nightmare).

Did any of you do this with this library? I am looking for a simple example I could get some inspiration from. The documentation provided is just too slim and I get lost in the example as it is not implemented for a webservice.

Thanks a lot for your help !

---

Here is the documentation for the first library I was talking about regarding a provider implementation :

Implementation Steps :

-> 3 interfaces need to be implemented, for the 3 different stores required by the default provider implementation.

IConsumerStore - a store for consumer details.
ITokenStore - a store for request and access tokens.
INonceStore - a store for nonces, unique strings supplied in requests - the provider checks to ensure requests aren't replayed by storing previous nonces in the nonce store.

-> Construct an OAuthProvider instance, providing a set of inspectors.

-> Wire up the provider to pages/controller actions/WCF operations etc.

I've had this from the beginning but I am very unsure about what some methods are about. I am working on it right now and will post here a detailed example of implementation once I'm done. I do not know if this will work but it looks fairly simple so far.

Comment: same applies for this library http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/

Comment: OAuth .NET has even less documentation... And I am working on the first one now. I don't want to go half way. Their wiki is incomplete, if you read some documentation of mine one day you will have tears of joy. People just don't know how to write these documents these days.